# How to replace full words versus substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dictionary

I am working on a problem where I am using a dictionary to replace certain words in a string.

This is my code for a minimal example:

```
dictionary = {"happy": 'YAY!', "happybday": "PARTY!"}

string = "There were so many happy people exclaiming happybday!"

for old_word, new_word in dictionary.items():
    string = string.replace(old_word, new_word)

print(string)
```

The problem here is I am getting the output:

```
There were so many YAY! people exclaiming YAY!bday!
```

Desired output:

```
There were so many YAY! people exclaiming PARTY!!
```

Clearly what is happening is that while iterating through each element in the dictionary, it is first seeing "happy" and then seeing that as a substring and replacing each instance of the substring. Where this is a problem is that in the second case, I the substring forms a larger string which should be replaced. However, when I iterate through each element in the dictionary it is only looking at the substring level.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might be able to fix this? I thought perhaps either reordering the items in the dictionary (so that the larger stings come first), but this does not seem like the best solution. I could also just simply split the string into a list of words and try to compare and replace based on this, but since this might take more time, I though that might not be the best solution either.

I think part of the problem might be occurring because of using the "in" keyword here, but I am not entirety sure.

Any advice? Any links to explanations, tutorials, or examples would be greatly appreciated. I am really trying to understand not only what to fix but what is wrong in the first place. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you want to have a priority of replacement.  In that case, you can process the key/value pairs in the desired order.

Comment: If order of application is important and If it's difficult to understand and define the order, I don't think you're going to be able to create an appropriate solution.

Comment: No problem!  Yes, it seems that length of the *old* value defines the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

You may build a regex alternation of search keys, sorted descending by length such that longer, more specific terms, will be searched first.

```py
dictionary = {"happy": 'YAY!', "happybday": "PARTY!"}
string = "There were so many happy people exclaiming happybday!"

regex = r'\b(?:' + r'|'.join(sorted(dictionary.keys(), key=len, reverse=True)) + r')\b'
output = re.sub(regex, lambda m: dictionary[m.group()], string)
print(output)

# There were so many YAY! people exclaiming PARTY!!
```

The significance of searching for longer keys first before shorter ones is that when we encounter `happybday`, we want to match it before matching `happy`.

Comment: Surely  the sorting is unnecessary when you are using `\b` for word boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

You can order the processing by the assumed order of precedence.
In your example it appears that length of the *key* should be enough.
(*from longest to shortest*)

```py
dictionary = {"happy": 'YAY!', "happybday": "PARTY!"}

string = "There were so many happy people exclaiming happybday!"

def by_length(item):    
    key, value = item
    return len(key)

for old_word, new_word in sorted(dictionary.items(), key=by_length, reverse=True):
    string = string.replace(old_word, new_word)
```